# Is it possible to link/sync 2 SharePoint lists together (that are being used as forms for users to fill out)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, workflow, infopath, list-form

IS it possible to link or sync 2 SharePoint lists together - more specifically I'm using the SharePoint lists for fillable forms, so if a user clicks "new Item" it pops open a form I made in InfoPath (where the columns are the question fields) for users to fill out.

My ask is this: If I have the main form (lets say 50 questions) that users will fill out - then I have a small list (5 questions - but it's 5 questions that are included in those 50) it's for a different team that just cares about those 5 questions - is it possible for one to send data to the other or sync?

Currently, once the big form of 50 questions is filled out, I will go in, look at the 5 questions, and then fill it out manually on the other form just for those 5 questions - obviously this is very tedious and can take a while - so I'm wondering if upon the main form being filled out if there is an action that can automatically create a new entry for the small list, and have it with those 5 questions.

Furthermore, to make things difficult, I have 2 fields/questions in that list that aren't from the original. So it's a list of 50 questions, and then a small list that has 5 questions from the 50 + 2 more that are brand new questions. Will that not work? Is it only going to work if it's the exact 5 questions to mirror?

Thanks for the help in advance - and I will be able to clarify further if needed.

Comment: Their is only one form which user filled, then one team wants only 5 questions from that form. is this correct? all data stored in the one list, right now you manually input the data in 2nd list?

Comment: That is correct - currently the way it is set up is they fill out the one list - then I manually do it for the second one. 

So lets say you filled out the list - you would come to me go to my form fill out the 50 questions - I would then take it, look for the 5 I car about and then manually put those 5 into the 2nd form.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep the data in a single list and create separate views for different teams.

List views can be created by opening the List Settings and create view.

Comment: Wow, honestly you're a genius. And the simplest answer at that. How did I not think of that?

I'm still perplexed how I didn't think of that.
I'll just make a new view called "Simple View" and only have it show those 5 questions... 

Thanks man for making me realize I'm WAY WAY WAY overthinking this!